# Google cloud compute not recognizing any resources

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've been playing around with the google cloud compute platform and everything was fine until all of a sudden last night it seemed unable to recognize any resources. Whenever I try to do anything, for example list current instances, I get:

```
$ gcloud compute instances list

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.list) Some requests did not succeed:
 - The resource 'projects/myProject' was not found
```

Everything seems to work fine through the web interface. I can launch an instance, look at it, link persistent disks, etc. It's only when I try to work through the command line interface that I have problems. And all of these commands worked fine until last night.

I've tried revoking my credentials and logging in again. I've double checked that my active credentialed account is a valid user on the project I'm trying to access. I've tried creating a new project and accessing that one. I've tried accessing a project that I don't own but on which I am an authorized user. I've even tried deleting the sdk toolkit and re-installing it. Nothing seems to work.

But I can ssh into an active instance just fine with: 
    gcloud compute --project "myProject" ssh --zone "us-central1-a" "instance-1"

Any thoughts? I have no idea what to try next. In case it matters, I'm on OSX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have checked what you describe and you are right, you cannot use the project name, you need to use the project ID like in [this link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/cloud-sdk) or the project number.

I have run this command:

```
gcloud config set project thisisnotarealproject
```

And I didn't receive any error. It seems that the gcloud command doesn't check if the project is correct or not. However I have seen with tcpdump that sends some packets and I suspect that this is to check the possible SDK updates and give you the message:

```
There are available updates for some Cloud SDK components.  To 
install them, please run:
$ gcloud components update
```

Then, when I type: `gcloud config list` I can see my fake project correctly configured but that's because that information is stored in the file `~/.config/gcloud/properties`.

In fact, if you modify that file and after that you type again `gcloud config list` you'll see how the value for the project changes.

So, to summarize, you can set the project using the:

- Project ID
- Project number

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

"Google Cloud Platform (GCP)" through "Command Line Interface (CLI)" tool [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/) need to be at first properly initialized

```
$ gcloud init
```

then after you be prompted to put "project" enter "Project ID" from your "[web console / projects](https://console.developers.google.com/project)" and

```
$ Enter project id you would like to use:
```

**if you set non-exist project name "CLI gcloud" will not return any errors**

Comment: Thanks. Using 'gcloud init' reset my config working. I have tried more than 1 days.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was doing all of my references to the project by name rather than ID. If you set a project by project name, it won't error, but it also won't actually give you access to any of that project's resources.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on multiple projects instead of configuring the default project add project as parameter in below syntax

> gcloud compute --project   instances list

example

```
gcloud compute --project www.stutzen.co  instances list
```